# How to prevent "iPhone is disabled" error when kids play with iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a baby who loves playing around with my iPhone XS. Naturally, she often plays with the passcode input buttons, and I get the "iPhone is disabled, Try again in X minutes" message, which I've googled and googled and there doesn't seem to be any way to turn it off. Not only is it annoying, but I'm worried that at some point she will enter the passcode wrong so many times, that the phone will be completely disabled.
I seem to recall in older iPhones I could just not have them require a passcode at all to wake, but this seems impossible now, unless I also want to disable Apple Pay, Face id to login etc. I'm fine with those requiring a passcode.
How can I prevent this dreaded "iPhone is disabled" error? I don't really care about the security it offers, with this lockdown I'm home all day anyway. ‍♀️

Comment: For what an iPhone costs, it's **not** a toy for a child to be playing with!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: Guided Access is perfect for this!
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202612

Not only does it lock the iPhone to a specific app, it even allows you to circle areas that will be inaccessible (e.g. on a camera, the take photo button)!